# Multiple SQL Aliases In Single Query MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aliases

I have the following query in mysql, and was wondering how I could insert multiple aliases at the same time, any help would be great!

```
mysql> 
SELECT emp_no,ROUND( AVG(salary), 2),DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y') AS Today 
FROM salaries 
GROUP BY emp_no 
LIMIT 10;
```

COLUMN HEADINGS:

```
| emp_no | ROUND( AVG(salary), 2) | Today      |
```

I'd like to have something like

```
| emp_no | avgSal | Today      |
```

Answer (score 3):

You have already done it for date, just need to add another one for average salary.

```
SELECT emp_no,
ROUND( AVG(salary), 2) as avgSal,
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y') AS Today 
FROM salaries 
GROUP BY emp_no 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Note the keyword 'AS' is optional. You can omit it if you want for readability/preference.